# regex not to match continuous numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-negation

I have the following regex, which matches numbers like *11:45 xyzz*, *abcd 22 30 xyz*, etc., where the numerals are time instances. But it also matches numeric instances like *32 11 43*. How do I avoid doing this?

```
(?<=\b)(\d{1,2}[\s:](\d{1,2}|o\'clock)[\s\.,]{0,1}(%s){0,1}?)(?=[\s\.,]|\Z)|(noon|midnight)(?=\b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [negative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) lookarounds, this will match a digit string not preceding or preceded by a digit:

```
(?<!\d)\s+\d+\s+(?!\d)
```